# Checking the input arguments to script to be empty failed in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

This a small bash program that is tasked with looking through a directory and counting how many files are in the directory. It's to ignore other directories and only count the files.

Below is my bash code, which seems to fail to count the files specifically in the directory, I say this because if I remove the if statement and just increment the counter the for loop continues to iterate and prints 4 in the counter (this is including directories though). With the if statement it prints this to the console.

```
folder1 has files
```

Looking at other questions I think the expression in my if statement is right and I am getting no compilation errors for syntax or another problems.

So I just simply dumbfounded as to why it is not counting the files.

```
 #!/bin/bash

folder=$1

if [ $1 = empty ]; then
    folder=empty
    counter=0
    echo $folder has $counter files
    exit
fi

for d in $(ls $folder); do
    if [[ -f $d ]]; then
        let 'counter++'
    fi
done

echo $folder has $counter files
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works for me, even though there are a number of improvements that could be made (including getting ride of the external program `ls`).  Should your check for `empty` be `[ -z $1 ]`, or maybe test `$#`?

Comment: That did fix the problem but I want to know why. Can you briefly help me understand why? Thank you.

Comment: Did you perhaps use a pipe rather than the code you show?

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`, See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire script could be very well simplified as below with enhancements made. Never use output of `ls` programmatically. It should be used *only* in the command-line. The `-z` construct allows to you assert if the parameter following it is empty or non-empty.

For looping over files, use the default glob expansion provided by the shell. Note the `&&` is a short-hand to do a action when the left-side of the operand returned a true condition, in a way short-hand equivalent of `if <condition>; then do <action>; fi`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { printf 'invalid argument passed\n' >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

shopt -s nullglob

for file in "$1"/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] && ((count++))
done

printf 'folder %s had %d files\n' "$1" "$count"
```